# Dynamic result set having problems with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I've tried writing and rewriting this several times, to keep it brief and yet, include "pertinent" background.  No luck, so I'm going to give the current situation and answer questions as asked.

I have two issues, so I'll put one in this post and the other in another post.

My problem is that my table, down to the tbody tag, is hard-coded into my JSP.  The rows in the tbody tag are returned from an AJAX call, based upon user input.  When the user does multiple searches, I get the rows I expect, but when the table is sorted the rows sorted by the tablesorter include ALL of the rows from ALL of the searches.  So, tablesorter is caching and appending the rows - creating a very unacceptable experience for the users and a nightmare for me.

Is there a way to reset the tablesorter cache with each sort, to what is currently in the table?  Otherwise, I believe I'm going to have to write my own table sorting script.  Not something I had on my list of "want to do" this week.

Comment: Don't add Solved to the title.  Instead, post your solution as an answer to your own question, and then mark your own answer as answered.  You must wait 24 hours to mark your own answer, however.  StackOverflow discourages adding things like this to the title of the question as it makes searching more difficult.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** I BELIEVE I'VE SOLVED THIS ***

Here is the code that I finally ended up using:

```
$("#resultsTbody").html(response);
$(".stripeMe").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra'] });
$(".stripeMe").trigger("update");
```

Apparently, using the *.trigger("update");* call clears the cache.  Took some doing, but I finally found it in the forums and then in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.trigger("update");
```

`widgetOptions : { filter_reset : '.reset' }` won't help, even if you are updating the table after the page loads using Ajax calls.